# Nested Map withDefaultValue changes default value

Tags: scala, dictionary, default-value, mutable

I have a mutable map containing another mutable map, both with default values. After I assign a value to one key in the enclosed map, its default value seems to change. 
I.e. I expected anotherDefault to have the value Map(1 -> default), NOT  Map(1 -> something).

Why is this happening?

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.{Map => MMap}
import scala.collection.mutable.{Map=>MMap}

scala> val amap = Map[Int, MMap[Int, String]]().withDefaultValue(MMap().withDefaultValue("default"))
amap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]] = Map()

scala> val bmap = amap(2)
bmap: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = Map()

scala> bmap(1)
res17: String = default

scala> bmap(1) = "something"

scala> val anotherDefault = amap(3)
anotherDefault: scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> something)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The outer map (`amap`) is creating a single instance of the inner map to use as the default. When you access this via `val bmap = amap(2)`, then modify `bmap`, you are modifying the single default map used by `amap`. When you call `amap(3)`, you then get back this default map, which is now a map with the key/value pair `(1 -> "something")`.

What you probably want is `withDefault`, not `withDefaultValue`, although it needs some extra argument/type specification to work:

```
val amap = Map[Int, MMap[Int, String]]().withDefault(x => MMap[Int, String]().withDefaultValue("default"))
```

Comment: If this is the case, it means that withDefaultValue() on a mutable map is useless, or even misleading?

Comment: Not at all - `bmap(4)` will still produce value "default", rather than throw a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: So a defaultValue is not immutable, and we can unknowingly change the default. That is somewhat unexpected.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification with withDefault()!

Comment: The default value you provided is not immutable simply because you provided a mutable map. If you provided an immutable map, then your default value would indeed be immutable.